# c - Implementation of queue using linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, queue

I tried to do implementation of queue by using linked list, but there always occurred error: incompatible types in assignment and assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Queue.h"

struct QUEUE_ELEMENT{
int element;
struct QUEUE_ELEMENT *next;
};

int size;
struct QUEUE_ELEMENT *head, *tail;

void initQueue(){

    head = NULL;
    tail = NULL;
    size = 0;

}       // void initQueue()



int queueEmpty(void) {

return (head == NULL && tail == NULL);

}   // int queueEmpty(void)





int enqueue(QUEUE_ELEMENT e) {
struct QUEUE_ELEMENT *temp;
if (tail == NULL){
    tail -> next = NULL;
    tail -> element = e;
    head = tail;
}
else {
    temp = malloc(sizeof(QUEUE_ELEMENT));
    tail -> next = temp;
    temp -> element = e;
    temp -> next = NULL;
    tail = temp;
}
return size++;

}   //  int enqueue(QUEUE_ELEMENT e)





int dequeue(QUEUE_ELEMENT *e){
struct QUEUE_ELEMENT *temp;
temp = malloc(sizeof(QUEUE_ELEMENT));

if (queueEmpty() != 0 ){
    temp = head;
    if(temp -> next != NULL){
    temp = temp -> next;
    free(head);
    head = temp;
    }
    else{
        free(head);
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
    }
}
    return size--;


}   //  int dequeue(QUEUE_ELEMENT *e)
```

I revised my code a lot.

Why 'tail -> element = e;' in enqueue() occurs error 'incompatible types in assignment'? How can I fix it?

Comment: Where??? post the actual compiler error

Comment: That "node" with `size`, `head`, `tail`, *and* `next` doesn't look like a good design ..

Comment: There are so many bugs in this code, that it makes my head hurt... Why do you need so many pointers for a simple linked list?

Comment: In each of these scopes you are separately creating linked lists. Never freeing. Lots of memory leaks with no recovery between function scope.

Comment: This: `if (tail == NULL) { tail -> next = NULL; ...` is just one example of the repetitious instances of *undefined behavior* in this code. Until you have a reasonable understanding of how pointers work in C, this task will be your undoing.

Comment: Note that the arrow `->` and dot `.` operators bind extremely tightly and should never be used with spaces around them.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a homework or for a real need? For the first one I won't say anything. But if you need it in practice, it's better to use already implemented solution.

There is a popular style where, in a linked list, head looks like a usual entry and the only thing which distinguishes it is the head pointer value itself. The first good example is Linux linked lists implementation ([a description](http://kernelnewbies.org/FAQ/LinkedLists)). Its specifics is a trick to get the whole entry address from its link member. This one is trivial to study and can answer your goals immediately.

The second good example is BSD list and queue macro set (a [manpage](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=queue&apropos=0&sektion=3&manpath=FreeBSD%2010.0-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html); particularly, you could start with TAILQ macro set). It's more cumbersome due to some tricks (e.g. forward pointers address link field but backward pointers address the whole structure) but still efficient.

I hope both can satisfy you and prevent reinventing a wheel :)

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning `tail->element`, which is an int, to `e` which is a `QUEUE_ELEMENT`. if you want to access the element in `e` you have to deference it like you did with tail first.
so `tail->element = e->element`

Comment: I am sorry, I looked at dequeue for a second, then just e.element . another tip, you are checking if tail is NULL then trying  to deference it and assign values to it, that's a segmentation fault. you must first allocate memory or assign it to another pointer